# How to use text file to load data and assign it to a variable?

Tags: python

i am new to python(learner).I created a simple program which asks for username and password and i used `getpass()`function to hide password
.But i want my program to load username and password from a text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import getpass
import os
print (' ')
print (' ')
print ('Please enter username and password in order to continue :')
print (' ')
print (' ')
user = (str(input('           USERNAME : ')))
usr_list = open("usr.txt", "r")
for line in usr_list:
  line.strip()
  if line == user:
    password = getpass.getpass("           PASSWORD : ")
    if password == 'root':
      os.system("python3 cross.py")
    else:
      print ('WRONG! Password')
      os.system("python3 sec.py")
  else:
    print ('WRONG! Username')
    os.system("python3 sec.py")
```

now, if i remove text file and open function from code and insert a string like "user1" `if user == "user1":` it works fine.

Comment: You want to hide password in textfile, or only load username and password from textfile?

Comment: i just want to store usernames and passwords in txt file and want to load these username and passwords in code and by boolean expressions want to check if it's right or not it decide real code will execute or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read data from text file simple:

```
with open('your_text_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    username = f.readline()
    password = f.readline()
```

This is mean that you are open file "your_text_file.txt" for reading ('r' as second parameter) and we read first line, after that we read the next line

This is work if your username and password write in the different line:

your_text_file.txt:

```
sume_username
verylongandstrongpassword
```

You can read about read and write file [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Firstly he would have to **write** the inputs into the file.

Comment: He asked only hove to read data from file, of course he must write to file before he read, but for his purpose he can do this without python

Comment: i tried it but whenever i load username.txt it load the file evan it print the data but boolean expressions for string is not working like( inside txt ::: 1.. user1\n 2..user2 ) and x = "user2". But when i try if y == "user2":   break . It doesn't work.

Comment: Try to do `y.strip()` this function is trim whitespace before and after word('\n', '\t' ' '). If it is not worked do `print(y)` and write to me the output

Comment: file = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in file:
  line.strip(" ")
  if line == "user6":
    print ("done")
  else:
    print ("not working")
    
# this code is not working it always print "not working" six times(because of six lines in file)

Comment: also i just noticed when i use only a sinlge line in txt file(user1   only) this code is working. so i think there is a way to write strings in txt file(a special character at the end of line or anything else like this which make sure that code load the second line not white space)

Comment: After line you have \n symbol, please write to me output not of `print("done")` write output of `print(line)`. and do `line.strip()` instead of `line.strip(" ")` when you pass first argument to strip you trim only whitespace, but without first argument you strip all of these character(\n,\t \r)

Comment: file = open("test.txt", "r")
for line in file:
  line.strip()
  print (line)
  if line == "user4":
    print ("done")


# it shows::: user1 "blanke line" user2 "blanke line" user3 "blanke line"........user6 "blanke line"  still not working

Comment: Add to you questions your full code plz. If you do all what i say it must work!

Comment: okey i updated the question with my real code and it's still not working.This code is working only when i use a single string in code to make the if statement True.

Comment: OMG, please tell me WHERE do you use `line.strip` as i say!!! You are reading what i say to you or not?

Comment: i used it not in this code but in sample code look at above comments.You can try this code in your environment(i updated this code with line.strip() it still not working).please.........

Comment: Strip function not change the string value, they only return new value, so your code `line.strip()` do nothing, you must do `line = line.strip()` and all will work fine

Comment: Thank You  sir it's working. actually i'm learning python on my own and i'm not from IT field so your help become more important to me

Comment: If my answer help you mark it as answer for your question please